# Android Independent Background Service

Tags: android

I need to develop an Android application. In this application, I need a background service running continuously. Main application will save data in files and background service will keep uploading that data to server. I want this service to run in background even if main application is closed or has been restarted.

I am not sure how to achieve this task.

Please help.

Regards,
Vito

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use WorkManager here rather than creating your own background service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I checked and found that Work Manager has minimum interval of 15 minutes. I need at least 5 minutes interval. Kindly suggest.